# PHP "supported scripts" (e.g. Cyrillic, Han etc) - definition of the unicode ranges for these?

Tags: php, unicode

I see in the PHP online manual (https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php) that there is a long list of predefined "supported scripts", which is largely helpful in detecting if a string contains, say, Cyrillic, Han or whatever. However, that long list doesn't include a definition of what Unicode, er, "characters" are included in those predefined identities. Many are "obvious" (or one might expect them to overlap with the Unicode blocks (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_block), but several are not, such as "Common" and "Inherited" (these are mentioned in that Wikipedia page re Unicode blocks, but without the specifics - e.g. "Inherited (2 characters)" in the block range U+0400..U+04FF, but without saying which 2 characters in that range). Outside of the Zend source code, is there a public specification of the ranges covered by these predefined identities?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the data file [Scripts.txt](https://unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/Scripts.txt) in the Unicode Standard.

Comment: That's a really helpful reference, thanks. However, either by definition (within PHP) or by "bug" (in the PHP implementation for my platform?), there is at least one discrepancy between the reference you provided and actual testing. The "Inherited" definition for characters 0-0x10fff (my upper limit used in testing) within that Unicode.org doc covers 1ABF..1ACE but the PHP implementation of support script "Inherited" doesn't. I haven't exhaustively checked all the other Script definitions, so there may be other discrepancies.

Comment: U+1ABF..U+1ACE are relatively new characters, added in Unicode 13.0 or later. The list of supported scripts on that manual page doesn’t include any writing systems added in Unicode 7.0 or later at all, so if that list is still accurate then PHP’s Unicode implementation is at least eight years out of date.

Comment: my PHP version 7.4.3 *is* out of date (latest PHP 7.4 is currently 7.4.30); PHP 8.0.22, 8.1.9 and 8.2.0 are all currently available - but I'm constrained either by OS or service provider availability. Useful input - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I decided in the end that references to non-PHP documentation, although very helpful (especially given the provenance of Unicode.org), won't necessarily reflect exactly the PHP implementations of its own supported Scripts. So I wrote the following PHP that tests every character in the range 0-0x10ffff

```
<?php

$scriptNames = array(
    'Arabic',
    'Armenian',
    'Avestan',
    'Balinese',
    'Bamum',
    'Batak',
    'Bengali',
    'Bopomofo',
    'Brahmi',
    'Braille',
    'Buginese',
    'Buhid',
    'Canadian_Aboriginal',
    'Carian',
    'Chakma',
    'Cham',
    'Cherokee',
    'Common',
    'Coptic',
    'Cuneiform',
    'Cypriot',
    'Cyrillic',
    'Deseret',
    'Devanagari',
    'Egyptian_Hieroglyphs',
    'Ethiopic',
    'Georgian',
    'Glagolitic',
    'Gothic',
    'Greek',
    'Gujarati',
    'Gurmukhi',
    'Han',
    'Hangul',
    'Hanunoo',
    'Hebrew',
    'Hiragana',
    'Imperial_Aramaic',
    'Inherited',
    'Inscriptional_Pahlavi',
    'Inscriptional_Parthian',
    'Javanese',
    'Kaithi',
    'Kannada',
    'Katakana',
    'Kayah_Li',
    'Kharoshthi',
    'Khmer',
    'Lao',
    'Latin',
    'Lepcha',
    'Limbu',
    'Linear_B',
    'Lisu',
    'Lycian',
    'Lydian',
    'Malayalam',
    'Mandaic',
    'Meetei_Mayek',
    'Meroitic_Cursive',
    'Meroitic_Hieroglyphs',
    'Miao',
    'Mongolian',
    'Myanmar',
    'New_Tai_Lue',
    'Nko',
    'Ogham',
    'Old_Italic',
    'Old_Persian',
    'Old_South_Arabian',
    'Old_Turkic',
    'Ol_Chiki',
    'Oriya',
    'Osmanya',
    'Phags_Pa',
    'Phoenician',
    'Rejang',
    'Runic',
    'Samaritan',
    'Saurashtra',
    'Sharada',
    'Shavian',
    'Sinhala',
    'Sora_Sompeng',
    'Sundanese',
    'Syloti_Nagri',
    'Syriac',
    'Tagalog',
    'Tagbanwa',
    'Tai_Le',
    'Tai_Tham',
    'Tai_Viet',
    'Takri',
    'Tamil',
    'Telugu',
    'Thaana',
    'Thai',
    'Tibetan',
    'Tifinagh',
    'Ugaritic',
    'Vai',
    'Yi'
);
$scriptTypes = array();
foreach( $scriptNames as $n ) $scriptTypes[ $n ] = array();
for( $i=0; $i <= 0x10ffff; $i++ ) {

    foreach( $scriptNames as $scriptName ) {

        if ( preg_match( '/[\p{'. $scriptName .'}]/u', mb_chr( $i, 'UTF-8') ) ) {

            if (empty( $scriptTypes[ $scriptName ])
                || ( ($i - $scriptTypes[ $scriptName ][ count( $scriptTypes[ $scriptName ] ) - 1 ][1]) > 1)
            ) {

                $scriptTypes[ $scriptName ][] = [$i, $i];

            } else {

                $scriptTypes[ $scriptName ][ count( $scriptTypes[ $scriptName ] ) - 1 ][1] = $i;
            }
        }
    }
}
foreach( $scriptTypes as $scriptName => $unicodeRanges ) {

    $cc ='';
    $n=0;
    foreach( $unicodeRanges as $r ) {

        $cc .= sprintf(
            '\x{%04x}',
            $r[0]
        );
        $n++;
        if ($r[1] > $r[0] ) {

            $cc .= sprintf(
                '-\x{%04x}',
                $r[1]
            );
            $n += $r[1] - $r[0];
        }
    }
    printf(
        '%s(%d)=[%s]'.PHP_EOL,
        $scriptName,
        $n,
        $cc
    );
}
```

This gives the following output in the form `<Name>(<code points covered>)=<PCRE character class>`:

```
Arabic(1281)=[\x{0600}-\x{0604}\x{0606}-\x{060b}\x{060d}-\x{061a}\x{061c}\x{061e}\x{0620}-\x{063f}\x{0641}-\x{064a}\x{0656}-\x{066f}\x{0671}-\x{06dc}\x{06de}-\x{06ff}\x{0750}-\x{077f}\x{08a0}-\x{08b4}\x{08b6}-\x{08bd}\x{08d3}-\x{08e1}\x{08e3}-\x{08ff}\x{fb50}-\x{fbc1}\x{fbd3}-\x{fd3d}\x{fd50}-\x{fd8f}\x{fd92}-\x{fdc7}\x{fdf0}-\x{fdfd}\x{fe70}-\x{fe74}\x{fe76}-\x{fefc}\x{10e60}-\x{10e7e}\x{1ee00}-\x{1ee03}\x{1ee05}-\x{1ee1f}\x{1ee21}-\x{1ee22}\x{1ee24}\x{1ee27}\x{1ee29}-\x{1ee32}\x{1ee34}-\x{1ee37}\x{1ee39}\x{1ee3b}\x{1ee42}\x{1ee47}\x{1ee49}\x{1ee4b}\x{1ee4d}-\x{1ee4f}\x{1ee51}-\x{1ee52}\x{1ee54}\x{1ee57}\x{1ee59}\x{1ee5b}\x{1ee5d}\x{1ee5f}\x{1ee61}-\x{1ee62}\x{1ee64}\x{1ee67}-\x{1ee6a}\x{1ee6c}-\x{1ee72}\x{1ee74}-\x{1ee77}\x{1ee79}-\x{1ee7c}\x{1ee7e}\x{1ee80}-\x{1ee89}\x{1ee8b}-\x{1ee9b}\x{1eea1}-\x{1eea3}\x{1eea5}-\x{1eea9}\x{1eeab}-\x{1eebb}\x{1eef0}-\x{1eef1}]
Armenian(95)=[\x{0531}-\x{0556}\x{0559}-\x{0588}\x{058a}\x{058d}-\x{058f}\x{fb13}-\x{fb17}]
Avestan(61)=[\x{10b00}-\x{10b35}\x{10b39}-\x{10b3f}]
Balinese(121)=[\x{1b00}-\x{1b4b}\x{1b50}-\x{1b7c}]
Bamum(657)=[\x{a6a0}-\x{a6f7}\x{16800}-\x{16a38}]
Batak(56)=[\x{1bc0}-\x{1bf3}\x{1bfc}-\x{1bff}]
Bengali(96)=[\x{0980}-\x{0983}\x{0985}-\x{098c}\x{098f}-\x{0990}\x{0993}-\x{09a8}\x{09aa}-\x{09b0}\x{09b2}\x{09b6}-\x{09b9}\x{09bc}-\x{09c4}\x{09c7}-\x{09c8}\x{09cb}-\x{09ce}\x{09d7}\x{09dc}-\x{09dd}\x{09df}-\x{09e3}\x{09e6}-\x{09fe}]
Bopomofo(72)=[\x{02ea}-\x{02eb}\x{3105}-\x{312f}\x{31a0}-\x{31ba}]
Brahmi(109)=[\x{11000}-\x{1104d}\x{11052}-\x{1106f}\x{1107f}]
Braille(256)=[\x{2800}-\x{28ff}]
Buginese(30)=[\x{1a00}-\x{1a1b}\x{1a1e}-\x{1a1f}]
Buhid(20)=[\x{1740}-\x{1753}]
Canadian_Aboriginal(710)=[\x{1400}-\x{167f}\x{18b0}-\x{18f5}]
Carian(49)=[\x{102a0}-\x{102d0}]
Chakma(70)=[\x{11100}-\x{11134}\x{11136}-\x{11146}]
Cham(83)=[\x{aa00}-\x{aa36}\x{aa40}-\x{aa4d}\x{aa50}-\x{aa59}\x{aa5c}-\x{aa5f}]
Cherokee(172)=[\x{13a0}-\x{13f5}\x{13f8}-\x{13fd}\x{ab70}-\x{abbf}]
Common(7805)=[\x{0000}-\x{0040}\x{005b}-\x{0060}\x{007b}-\x{00a9}\x{00ab}-\x{00b9}\x{00bb}-\x{00bf}\x{00d7}\x{00f7}\x{02b9}-\x{02df}\x{02e5}-\x{02e9}\x{02ec}-\x{02ff}\x{0374}\x{037e}\x{0385}\x{0387}\x{0589}\x{0605}\x{060c}\x{061b}\x{061f}\x{0640}\x{06dd}\x{08e2}\x{0964}-\x{0965}\x{0e3f}\x{0fd5}-\x{0fd8}\x{10fb}\x{16eb}-\x{16ed}\x{1735}-\x{1736}\x{1802}-\x{1803}\x{1805}\x{1cd3}\x{1ce1}\x{1ce9}-\x{1cec}\x{1cee}-\x{1cf3}\x{1cf5}-\x{1cf7}\x{1cfa}\x{2000}-\x{200b}\x{200e}-\x{2064}\x{2066}-\x{2070}\x{2074}-\x{207e}\x{2080}-\x{208e}\x{20a0}-\x{20bf}\x{2100}-\x{2125}\x{2127}-\x{2129}\x{212c}-\x{2131}\x{2133}-\x{214d}\x{214f}-\x{215f}\x{2189}-\x{218b}\x{2190}-\x{2426}\x{2440}-\x{244a}\x{2460}-\x{27ff}\x{2900}-\x{2b73}\x{2b76}-\x{2b95}\x{2b98}-\x{2bff}\x{2e00}-\x{2e4f}\x{2ff0}-\x{2ffb}\x{3000}-\x{3004}\x{3006}\x{3008}-\x{3020}\x{3030}-\x{3037}\x{303c}-\x{303f}\x{309b}-\x{309c}\x{30a0}\x{30fb}-\x{30fc}\x{3190}-\x{319f}\x{31c0}-\x{31e3}\x{3220}-\x{325f}\x{327f}-\x{32cf}\x{32ff}\x{3358}-\x{33ff}\x{4dc0}-\x{4dff}\x{a700}-\x{a721}\x{a788}-\x{a78a}\x{a830}-\x{a839}\x{a92e}\x{a9cf}\x{ab5b}\x{fd3e}-\x{fd3f}\x{fe10}-\x{fe19}\x{fe30}-\x{fe52}\x{fe54}-\x{fe66}\x{fe68}-\x{fe6b}\x{feff}\x{ff01}-\x{ff20}\x{ff3b}-\x{ff40}\x{ff5b}-\x{ff65}\x{ff70}\x{ff9e}-\x{ff9f}\x{ffe0}-\x{ffe6}\x{ffe8}-\x{ffee}\x{fff9}-\x{fffd}\x{10100}-\x{10102}\x{10107}-\x{10133}\x{10137}-\x{1013f}\x{10190}-\x{1019b}\x{101d0}-\x{101fc}\x{102e1}-\x{102fb}\x{16fe2}-\x{16fe3}\x{1bca0}-\x{1bca3}\x{1d000}-\x{1d0f5}\x{1d100}-\x{1d126}\x{1d129}-\x{1d166}\x{1d16a}-\x{1d17a}\x{1d183}-\x{1d184}\x{1d18c}-\x{1d1a9}\x{1d1ae}-\x{1d1e8}\x{1d2e0}-\x{1d2f3}\x{1d300}-\x{1d356}\x{1d360}-\x{1d378}\x{1d400}-\x{1d454}\x{1d456}-\x{1d49c}\x{1d49e}-\x{1d49f}\x{1d4a2}\x{1d4a5}-\x{1d4a6}\x{1d4a9}-\x{1d4ac}\x{1d4ae}-\x{1d4b9}\x{1d4bb}\x{1d4bd}-\x{1d4c3}\x{1d4c5}-\x{1d505}\x{1d507}-\x{1d50a}\x{1d50d}-\x{1d514}\x{1d516}-\x{1d51c}\x{1d51e}-\x{1d539}\x{1d53b}-\x{1d53e}\x{1d540}-\x{1d544}\x{1d546}\x{1d54a}-\x{1d550}\x{1d552}-\x{1d6a5}\x{1d6a8}-\x{1d7cb}\x{1d7ce}-\x{1d7ff}\x{1ec71}-\x{1ecb4}\x{1ed01}-\x{1ed3d}\x{1f000}-\x{1f02b}\x{1f030}-\x{1f093}\x{1f0a0}-\x{1f0ae}\x{1f0b1}-\x{1f0bf}\x{1f0c1}-\x{1f0cf}\x{1f0d1}-\x{1f0f5}\x{1f100}-\x{1f10c}\x{1f110}-\x{1f16c}\x{1f170}-\x{1f1ac}\x{1f1e6}-\x{1f1ff}\x{1f201}-\x{1f202}\x{1f210}-\x{1f23b}\x{1f240}-\x{1f248}\x{1f250}-\x{1f251}\x{1f260}-\x{1f265}\x{1f300}-\x{1f6d5}\x{1f6e0}-\x{1f6ec}\x{1f6f0}-\x{1f6fa}\x{1f700}-\x{1f773}\x{1f780}-\x{1f7d8}\x{1f7e0}-\x{1f7eb}\x{1f800}-\x{1f80b}\x{1f810}-\x{1f847}\x{1f850}-\x{1f859}\x{1f860}-\x{1f887}\x{1f890}-\x{1f8ad}\x{1f900}-\x{1f90b}\x{1f90d}-\x{1f971}\x{1f973}-\x{1f976}\x{1f97a}-\x{1f9a2}\x{1f9a5}-\x{1f9aa}\x{1f9ae}-\x{1f9ca}\x{1f9cd}-\x{1fa53}\x{1fa60}-\x{1fa6d}\x{1fa70}-\x{1fa73}\x{1fa78}-\x{1fa7a}\x{1fa80}-\x{1fa82}\x{1fa90}-\x{1fa95}\x{e0001}\x{e0020}-\x{e007f}]
Coptic(137)=[\x{03e2}-\x{03ef}\x{2c80}-\x{2cf3}\x{2cf9}-\x{2cff}]
Cuneiform(1234)=[\x{12000}-\x{12399}\x{12400}-\x{1246e}\x{12470}-\x{12474}\x{12480}-\x{12543}]
Cypriot(55)=[\x{10800}-\x{10805}\x{10808}\x{1080a}-\x{10835}\x{10837}-\x{10838}\x{1083c}\x{1083f}]
Cyrillic(443)=[\x{0400}-\x{0484}\x{0487}-\x{052f}\x{1c80}-\x{1c88}\x{1d2b}\x{1d78}\x{2de0}-\x{2dff}\x{a640}-\x{a69f}\x{fe2e}-\x{fe2f}]
Deseret(80)=[\x{10400}-\x{1044f}]
Devanagari(154)=[\x{0900}-\x{0950}\x{0955}-\x{0963}\x{0966}-\x{097f}\x{a8e0}-\x{a8ff}]
Egyptian_Hieroglyphs(1080)=[\x{13000}-\x{1342e}\x{13430}-\x{13438}]
Ethiopic(495)=[\x{1200}-\x{1248}\x{124a}-\x{124d}\x{1250}-\x{1256}\x{1258}\x{125a}-\x{125d}\x{1260}-\x{1288}\x{128a}-\x{128d}\x{1290}-\x{12b0}\x{12b2}-\x{12b5}\x{12b8}-\x{12be}\x{12c0}\x{12c2}-\x{12c5}\x{12c8}-\x{12d6}\x{12d8}-\x{1310}\x{1312}-\x{1315}\x{1318}-\x{135a}\x{135d}-\x{137c}\x{1380}-\x{1399}\x{2d80}-\x{2d96}\x{2da0}-\x{2da6}\x{2da8}-\x{2dae}\x{2db0}-\x{2db6}\x{2db8}-\x{2dbe}\x{2dc0}-\x{2dc6}\x{2dc8}-\x{2dce}\x{2dd0}-\x{2dd6}\x{2dd8}-\x{2dde}\x{ab01}-\x{ab06}\x{ab09}-\x{ab0e}\x{ab11}-\x{ab16}\x{ab20}-\x{ab26}\x{ab28}-\x{ab2e}]
Georgian(173)=[\x{10a0}-\x{10c5}\x{10c7}\x{10cd}\x{10d0}-\x{10fa}\x{10fc}-\x{10ff}\x{1c90}-\x{1cba}\x{1cbd}-\x{1cbf}\x{2d00}-\x{2d25}\x{2d27}\x{2d2d}]
Glagolitic(132)=[\x{2c00}-\x{2c2e}\x{2c30}-\x{2c5e}\x{1e000}-\x{1e006}\x{1e008}-\x{1e018}\x{1e01b}-\x{1e021}\x{1e023}-\x{1e024}\x{1e026}-\x{1e02a}]
Gothic(27)=[\x{10330}-\x{1034a}]
Greek(518)=[\x{0370}-\x{0373}\x{0375}-\x{0377}\x{037a}-\x{037d}\x{037f}\x{0384}\x{0386}\x{0388}-\x{038a}\x{038c}\x{038e}-\x{03a1}\x{03a3}-\x{03e1}\x{03f0}-\x{03ff}\x{1d26}-\x{1d2a}\x{1d5d}-\x{1d61}\x{1d66}-\x{1d6a}\x{1dbf}\x{1f00}-\x{1f15}\x{1f18}-\x{1f1d}\x{1f20}-\x{1f45}\x{1f48}-\x{1f4d}\x{1f50}-\x{1f57}\x{1f59}\x{1f5b}\x{1f5d}\x{1f5f}-\x{1f7d}\x{1f80}-\x{1fb4}\x{1fb6}-\x{1fc4}\x{1fc6}-\x{1fd3}\x{1fd6}-\x{1fdb}\x{1fdd}-\x{1fef}\x{1ff2}-\x{1ff4}\x{1ff6}-\x{1ffe}\x{2126}\x{ab65}\x{10140}-\x{1018e}\x{101a0}\x{1d200}-\x{1d245}]
Gujarati(91)=[\x{0a81}-\x{0a83}\x{0a85}-\x{0a8d}\x{0a8f}-\x{0a91}\x{0a93}-\x{0aa8}\x{0aaa}-\x{0ab0}\x{0ab2}-\x{0ab3}\x{0ab5}-\x{0ab9}\x{0abc}-\x{0ac5}\x{0ac7}-\x{0ac9}\x{0acb}-\x{0acd}\x{0ad0}\x{0ae0}-\x{0ae3}\x{0ae6}-\x{0af1}\x{0af9}-\x{0aff}]
Gurmukhi(80)=[\x{0a01}-\x{0a03}\x{0a05}-\x{0a0a}\x{0a0f}-\x{0a10}\x{0a13}-\x{0a28}\x{0a2a}-\x{0a30}\x{0a32}-\x{0a33}\x{0a35}-\x{0a36}\x{0a38}-\x{0a39}\x{0a3c}\x{0a3e}-\x{0a42}\x{0a47}-\x{0a48}\x{0a4b}-\x{0a4d}\x{0a51}\x{0a59}-\x{0a5c}\x{0a5e}\x{0a66}-\x{0a76}]
Han(89233)=[\x{2e80}-\x{2e99}\x{2e9b}-\x{2ef3}\x{2f00}-\x{2fd5}\x{3005}\x{3007}\x{3021}-\x{3029}\x{3038}-\x{303b}\x{3400}-\x{4db5}\x{4e00}-\x{9fef}\x{f900}-\x{fa6d}\x{fa70}-\x{fad9}\x{20000}-\x{2a6d6}\x{2a700}-\x{2b734}\x{2b740}-\x{2b81d}\x{2b820}-\x{2cea1}\x{2ceb0}-\x{2ebe0}\x{2f800}-\x{2fa1d}]
Hangul(11739)=[\x{1100}-\x{11ff}\x{302e}-\x{302f}\x{3131}-\x{318e}\x{3200}-\x{321e}\x{3260}-\x{327e}\x{a960}-\x{a97c}\x{ac00}-\x{d7a3}\x{d7b0}-\x{d7c6}\x{d7cb}-\x{d7fb}\x{ffa0}-\x{ffbe}\x{ffc2}-\x{ffc7}\x{ffca}-\x{ffcf}\x{ffd2}-\x{ffd7}\x{ffda}-\x{ffdc}]
Hanunoo(21)=[\x{1720}-\x{1734}]
Hebrew(134)=[\x{0591}-\x{05c7}\x{05d0}-\x{05ea}\x{05ef}-\x{05f4}\x{fb1d}-\x{fb36}\x{fb38}-\x{fb3c}\x{fb3e}\x{fb40}-\x{fb41}\x{fb43}-\x{fb44}\x{fb46}-\x{fb4f}]
Hiragana(379)=[\x{3041}-\x{3096}\x{309d}-\x{309f}\x{1b001}-\x{1b11e}\x{1b150}-\x{1b152}\x{1f200}]
Imperial_Aramaic(31)=[\x{10840}-\x{10855}\x{10857}-\x{1085f}]
Inherited(571)=[\x{0300}-\x{036f}\x{0485}-\x{0486}\x{064b}-\x{0655}\x{0670}\x{0951}-\x{0954}\x{1ab0}-\x{1abe}\x{1cd0}-\x{1cd2}\x{1cd4}-\x{1ce0}\x{1ce2}-\x{1ce8}\x{1ced}\x{1cf4}\x{1cf8}-\x{1cf9}\x{1dc0}-\x{1df9}\x{1dfb}-\x{1dff}\x{200c}-\x{200d}\x{20d0}-\x{20f0}\x{302a}-\x{302d}\x{3099}-\x{309a}\x{fe00}-\x{fe0f}\x{fe20}-\x{fe2d}\x{101fd}\x{102e0}\x{1133b}\x{1d167}-\x{1d169}\x{1d17b}-\x{1d182}\x{1d185}-\x{1d18b}\x{1d1aa}-\x{1d1ad}\x{e0100}-\x{e01ef}]
Inscriptional_Pahlavi(27)=[\x{10b60}-\x{10b72}\x{10b78}-\x{10b7f}]
Inscriptional_Parthian(30)=[\x{10b40}-\x{10b55}\x{10b58}-\x{10b5f}]
Javanese(90)=[\x{a980}-\x{a9cd}\x{a9d0}-\x{a9d9}\x{a9de}-\x{a9df}]
Kaithi(67)=[\x{11080}-\x{110c1}\x{110cd}]
Kannada(89)=[\x{0c80}-\x{0c8c}\x{0c8e}-\x{0c90}\x{0c92}-\x{0ca8}\x{0caa}-\x{0cb3}\x{0cb5}-\x{0cb9}\x{0cbc}-\x{0cc4}\x{0cc6}-\x{0cc8}\x{0cca}-\x{0ccd}\x{0cd5}-\x{0cd6}\x{0cde}\x{0ce0}-\x{0ce3}\x{0ce6}-\x{0cef}\x{0cf1}-\x{0cf2}]
Katakana(304)=[\x{30a1}-\x{30fa}\x{30fd}-\x{30ff}\x{31f0}-\x{31ff}\x{32d0}-\x{32fe}\x{3300}-\x{3357}\x{ff66}-\x{ff6f}\x{ff71}-\x{ff9d}\x{1b000}\x{1b164}-\x{1b167}]
Kayah_Li(47)=[\x{a900}-\x{a92d}\x{a92f}]
Kharoshthi(68)=[\x{10a00}-\x{10a03}\x{10a05}-\x{10a06}\x{10a0c}-\x{10a13}\x{10a15}-\x{10a17}\x{10a19}-\x{10a35}\x{10a38}-\x{10a3a}\x{10a3f}-\x{10a48}\x{10a50}-\x{10a58}]
Khmer(146)=[\x{1780}-\x{17dd}\x{17e0}-\x{17e9}\x{17f0}-\x{17f9}\x{19e0}-\x{19ff}]
Lao(82)=[\x{0e81}-\x{0e82}\x{0e84}\x{0e86}-\x{0e8a}\x{0e8c}-\x{0ea3}\x{0ea5}\x{0ea7}-\x{0ebd}\x{0ec0}-\x{0ec4}\x{0ec6}\x{0ec8}-\x{0ecd}\x{0ed0}-\x{0ed9}\x{0edc}-\x{0edf}]
Latin(1366)=[\x{0041}-\x{005a}\x{0061}-\x{007a}\x{00aa}\x{00ba}\x{00c0}-\x{00d6}\x{00d8}-\x{00f6}\x{00f8}-\x{02b8}\x{02e0}-\x{02e4}\x{1d00}-\x{1d25}\x{1d2c}-\x{1d5c}\x{1d62}-\x{1d65}\x{1d6b}-\x{1d77}\x{1d79}-\x{1dbe}\x{1e00}-\x{1eff}\x{2071}\x{207f}\x{2090}-\x{209c}\x{212a}-\x{212b}\x{2132}\x{214e}\x{2160}-\x{2188}\x{2c60}-\x{2c7f}\x{a722}-\x{a787}\x{a78b}-\x{a7bf}\x{a7c2}-\x{a7c6}\x{a7f7}-\x{a7ff}\x{ab30}-\x{ab5a}\x{ab5c}-\x{ab64}\x{ab66}-\x{ab67}\x{fb00}-\x{fb06}\x{ff21}-\x{ff3a}\x{ff41}-\x{ff5a}]
Lepcha(74)=[\x{1c00}-\x{1c37}\x{1c3b}-\x{1c49}\x{1c4d}-\x{1c4f}]
Limbu(68)=[\x{1900}-\x{191e}\x{1920}-\x{192b}\x{1930}-\x{193b}\x{1940}\x{1944}-\x{194f}]
Linear_B(211)=[\x{10000}-\x{1000b}\x{1000d}-\x{10026}\x{10028}-\x{1003a}\x{1003c}-\x{1003d}\x{1003f}-\x{1004d}\x{10050}-\x{1005d}\x{10080}-\x{100fa}]
Lisu(48)=[\x{a4d0}-\x{a4ff}]
Lycian(29)=[\x{10280}-\x{1029c}]
Lydian(27)=[\x{10920}-\x{10939}\x{1093f}]
Malayalam(117)=[\x{0d00}-\x{0d03}\x{0d05}-\x{0d0c}\x{0d0e}-\x{0d10}\x{0d12}-\x{0d44}\x{0d46}-\x{0d48}\x{0d4a}-\x{0d4f}\x{0d54}-\x{0d63}\x{0d66}-\x{0d7f}]
Mandaic(29)=[\x{0840}-\x{085b}\x{085e}]
Meetei_Mayek(79)=[\x{aae0}-\x{aaf6}\x{abc0}-\x{abed}\x{abf0}-\x{abf9}]
Meroitic_Cursive(90)=[\x{109a0}-\x{109b7}\x{109bc}-\x{109cf}\x{109d2}-\x{109ff}]
Meroitic_Hieroglyphs(32)=[\x{10980}-\x{1099f}]
Miao(149)=[\x{16f00}-\x{16f4a}\x{16f4f}-\x{16f87}\x{16f8f}-\x{16f9f}]
Mongolian(167)=[\x{1800}-\x{1801}\x{1804}\x{1806}-\x{180e}\x{1810}-\x{1819}\x{1820}-\x{1878}\x{1880}-\x{18aa}\x{11660}-\x{1166c}]
Myanmar(223)=[\x{1000}-\x{109f}\x{a9e0}-\x{a9fe}\x{aa60}-\x{aa7f}]
New_Tai_Lue(83)=[\x{1980}-\x{19ab}\x{19b0}-\x{19c9}\x{19d0}-\x{19da}\x{19de}-\x{19df}]
Nko(62)=[\x{07c0}-\x{07fa}\x{07fd}-\x{07ff}]
Ogham(29)=[\x{1680}-\x{169c}]
Old_Italic(39)=[\x{10300}-\x{10323}\x{1032d}-\x{1032f}]
Old_Persian(50)=[\x{103a0}-\x{103c3}\x{103c8}-\x{103d5}]
Old_South_Arabian(32)=[\x{10a60}-\x{10a7f}]
Old_Turkic(73)=[\x{10c00}-\x{10c48}]
Ol_Chiki(48)=[\x{1c50}-\x{1c7f}]
Oriya(90)=[\x{0b01}-\x{0b03}\x{0b05}-\x{0b0c}\x{0b0f}-\x{0b10}\x{0b13}-\x{0b28}\x{0b2a}-\x{0b30}\x{0b32}-\x{0b33}\x{0b35}-\x{0b39}\x{0b3c}-\x{0b44}\x{0b47}-\x{0b48}\x{0b4b}-\x{0b4d}\x{0b56}-\x{0b57}\x{0b5c}-\x{0b5d}\x{0b5f}-\x{0b63}\x{0b66}-\x{0b77}]
Osmanya(40)=[\x{10480}-\x{1049d}\x{104a0}-\x{104a9}]
Phags_Pa(56)=[\x{a840}-\x{a877}]
Phoenician(29)=[\x{10900}-\x{1091b}\x{1091f}]
Rejang(37)=[\x{a930}-\x{a953}\x{a95f}]
Runic(86)=[\x{16a0}-\x{16ea}\x{16ee}-\x{16f8}]
Samaritan(61)=[\x{0800}-\x{082d}\x{0830}-\x{083e}]
Saurashtra(82)=[\x{a880}-\x{a8c5}\x{a8ce}-\x{a8d9}]
Sharada(94)=[\x{11180}-\x{111cd}\x{111d0}-\x{111df}]
Shavian(48)=[\x{10450}-\x{1047f}]
Sinhala(110)=[\x{0d82}-\x{0d83}\x{0d85}-\x{0d96}\x{0d9a}-\x{0db1}\x{0db3}-\x{0dbb}\x{0dbd}\x{0dc0}-\x{0dc6}\x{0dca}\x{0dcf}-\x{0dd4}\x{0dd6}\x{0dd8}-\x{0ddf}\x{0de6}-\x{0def}\x{0df2}-\x{0df4}\x{111e1}-\x{111f4}]
Sora_Sompeng(35)=[\x{110d0}-\x{110e8}\x{110f0}-\x{110f9}]
Sundanese(72)=[\x{1b80}-\x{1bbf}\x{1cc0}-\x{1cc7}]
Syloti_Nagri(44)=[\x{a800}-\x{a82b}]
Syriac(88)=[\x{0700}-\x{070d}\x{070f}-\x{074a}\x{074d}-\x{074f}\x{0860}-\x{086a}]
Tagalog(20)=[\x{1700}-\x{170c}\x{170e}-\x{1714}]
Tagbanwa(18)=[\x{1760}-\x{176c}\x{176e}-\x{1770}\x{1772}-\x{1773}]
Tai_Le(35)=[\x{1950}-\x{196d}\x{1970}-\x{1974}]
Tai_Tham(127)=[\x{1a20}-\x{1a5e}\x{1a60}-\x{1a7c}\x{1a7f}-\x{1a89}\x{1a90}-\x{1a99}\x{1aa0}-\x{1aad}]
Tai_Viet(72)=[\x{aa80}-\x{aac2}\x{aadb}-\x{aadf}]
Takri(67)=[\x{11680}-\x{116b8}\x{116c0}-\x{116c9}]
Tamil(123)=[\x{0b82}-\x{0b83}\x{0b85}-\x{0b8a}\x{0b8e}-\x{0b90}\x{0b92}-\x{0b95}\x{0b99}-\x{0b9a}\x{0b9c}\x{0b9e}-\x{0b9f}\x{0ba3}-\x{0ba4}\x{0ba8}-\x{0baa}\x{0bae}-\x{0bb9}\x{0bbe}-\x{0bc2}\x{0bc6}-\x{0bc8}\x{0bca}-\x{0bcd}\x{0bd0}\x{0bd7}\x{0be6}-\x{0bfa}\x{11fc0}-\x{11ff1}\x{11fff}]
Telugu(98)=[\x{0c00}-\x{0c0c}\x{0c0e}-\x{0c10}\x{0c12}-\x{0c28}\x{0c2a}-\x{0c39}\x{0c3d}-\x{0c44}\x{0c46}-\x{0c48}\x{0c4a}-\x{0c4d}\x{0c55}-\x{0c56}\x{0c58}-\x{0c5a}\x{0c60}-\x{0c63}\x{0c66}-\x{0c6f}\x{0c77}-\x{0c7f}]
Thaana(50)=[\x{0780}-\x{07b1}]
Thai(86)=[\x{0e01}-\x{0e3a}\x{0e40}-\x{0e5b}]
Tibetan(207)=[\x{0f00}-\x{0f47}\x{0f49}-\x{0f6c}\x{0f71}-\x{0f97}\x{0f99}-\x{0fbc}\x{0fbe}-\x{0fcc}\x{0fce}-\x{0fd4}\x{0fd9}-\x{0fda}]
Tifinagh(59)=[\x{2d30}-\x{2d67}\x{2d6f}-\x{2d70}\x{2d7f}]
Ugaritic(31)=[\x{10380}-\x{1039d}\x{1039f}]
Vai(300)=[\x{a500}-\x{a62b}]
Yi(1220)=[\x{a000}-\x{a48c}\x{a490}-\x{a4c6}]
```

I've only visually compared the "Inherited" script definition with the Unicode one (https://unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/Scripts.txt), but there are discrepancies in that, e.g. 0x1ABF..0x1ACE is covered by the Unicode definition, but not in the PHP implementation I'm using (7.4.3)